# Why does my simple, finite hypothesis test never stop?

Tags: python, pytest, python-hypothesis

I am running a test suite with hypothesis-4.24.6 and pytest-5.0.0. My test has a finite set of possible inputs, but hypothesis never finishes testing.

I have reduced it to the following minimal example, which I run as `pytest test.py`

```py
from hypothesis import given
import hypothesis.strategies as st


@given(x=st.just(0)
         | st.just(1),
       y=st.just(0)
         | st.just(1)
         | st.just(2))
def test_x_y(x, y):
    assert True
```

I would expect it to try all six combinations here and then succeed. Or possibly a small multiple of that to check for flakiness. Instead it runs indefinitely, (after about 15 mins of testing I kill it.)

If I interrupt the test, back traces seem to show it just continuously generating new examples.

What have I done wrong here?

Comment: This is clearly a regression that first occured with the 4.10 release. With the version 4.9, the test passes in 0.12 seconds, while with 4.10 and later it doesn't stop in >1 minute. I would create a [new issue](https://github.com/HypothesisWorks/hypothesis/issues/new), or summon [Zac Hatfield-Dodds](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9297601/zac-hatfield-dodds) and ask him.

Comment: I'm still looking into this, but it's clearly a bug!  Future details will be posted at https://github.com/HypothesisWorks/hypothesis/issues/2027

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug was fixed in Hypothesis <strike>4.26.2</strike>, or at least we thought so; it's *actually* fixed in 4.26.3 though: https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changes.html#v4-26-3

Comment: Just gave this a go: it does not seem to work with my example yet. I will add details to the github issue.

Comment: Thanks for following this up - it turns out that we fixed a masking bug, and needed a *second* fix for your actual problem.  But it's fixed now, as far as I know!

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be connected to the amount of successful tests `hypothesis` tries to generate:

```
>>> from hypothesis import given, strategies as st
>>> @given(st.integers(0,1), st.integers(0,2))
... def test(x, y):
...   print(x, y)
...   assert True
... 
>>> test()
0 0
1 1
1 0
1 2
1 1
0 1
0 0
1 2
0 2
0 2
1 0
1 2
0 1
0 1
1 2
[snip…]
```

See, [this part of the docs, for instance](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/details.html#making-assumptions), the default amount of successful test cases should be 100. So trying to generate more and more data to only restrict to 6 cases is rapidly failing to find one of these 6 cases.

The simplest approach can be to just [limit the amount of examples](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#hypothesis.settings.max_examples) needed for this test to pass:

```
>>> from hypothesis import settings
>>> @settings(max_examples=30)
... @given(st.integers(0,1), st.integers(0,2))
... def test(x, y):
...   print(x, y)
...   assert True
... 
>>> test()
0 0
1 1
1 0
0 2
1 2
0 1
0 1
1 1
1 0
1 1
0 1
1 2
1 1
0 0
0 2
0 2
0 0
1 2
1 0
0 1
1 0
1 0
0 1
1 2
1 1
0 2
0 0
1 2
0 0
0 2
```

---

An other approach, given the few amount of test cases, would be to explicit them all using [`@example`](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reproducing.html#hypothesis.example) and ask `hypothesis` to [only run those explicit examples](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#hypothesis.settings.phases):

```
>>> from hypothesis import given, example, settings, Phase, strategies as st
>>> @settings(phases=(Phase.explicit,))
... @given(x=st.integers(), y=st.integers())
... @example(x=0, y=0)
... @example(x=0, y=1)
... @example(x=0, y=2)
... @example(x=1, y=0)
... @example(x=1, y=1)
... @example(x=1, y=2)
... def test(x, y):
...   print(x, y)
...   assert True
... 
>>> test()
0 0
0 1
0 2
1 0
1 1
1 2
```

---

Also note that `st.just(0) | st.just(1)` is equivalent to `st.one_of(st.just(0), st.just(1))` so choose an approach and stick to it, but don't mix them.

Comment: Thanks for that last tip, I have made the example simpler. The problem seems likely a bug tho, since this actually works as expected in 4.9